# Firestore: isGreatThan not working in query (iOS)

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple query as follows:

```
db.collection("test").whereField("number", isEqualTo: 2)
```

This works perfectly.  However, if I replace isEqualTo with isGreaterThan then it finds nothing (yes, I have numbers greater than that number).  I have tried it on numbers and dates and no matter what the database content is I cannot get a query to produce anything on isGreaterThan or isGreaterThanOrEqualTo, only isEqualTo works.

Is there something secret to be done or is it broken?

Comment: Can you show us your database?

Comment: Well, it is simply a simple test database with one field in it called "test" and it's type has been changed to a string, number and timestamp to try and get the above working.  No matter what type, isEqualTo works, isGreaterThan does not.  So, it is not a real database it is just a one field database to work out why this does not work...  What are you looking for in the definition, I can send that.

Comment: @DavidCittadini I also face somewhat of a similar issue. In my case I need to find numbers within a range. So I use isGreaterThanOrEqualTo and isLessThanOrEqualTo. The query returns less numbers then expected. I know that there are more numbers in the range.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (equals works but greater than didn't) and in my case it's because you need to create an index for the field. If anyone else runs into this, check the error messages and there should also be an url link in the error message that will create the index for you.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it and this code worked for me. In the Firestore I saved a field in the document called orderNumber and set it to number

```
 let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("ProductOrders").whereField("orderNumber", isGreaterThan: 3).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in

        if error != nil{
            print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
        } else {
            for document in (snapshot?.documents)! {
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
            }}}
```